# `window.location.href` in client vs `res.redirect` in express

Tags: javascript, html, express, dom, browser

I want to send user to a certain link, there are 2 ways to getting there:

1. Browser Client Approach

- I call express endpoint `/redirect`
- It calculates the url to redirect to
- It returns the url to redirect to
- Client browser redirects via `window.location.href`

2. Express Server Approach

- I call express endpoint `/redirect`
- It calculates the url to redirect to
- It calls `res.redirect(url)`

Which is the best way? Is there any significant differences between these?

The current use case I'm looking into has documentation which showed the 2. express example. However I saw some use cases where the 1. browser approach is used

Comment: Is the express server used as "API" only or does it render parts of your page?

Comment: It is used for both use cases